# how to validate if a parameter is not contained in the request using wiremock (Using JSON)

Tags: wiremock

I'm implementing a mock for a /token endpoint that needs to return an error scenario.

```
{
  "mappings": [
    {
      "name": "Mock error 400: 'code' is not provided",
      "requet": {
        "method": "POST",
        "url": "/as/token.oauth2",
        "bodyPatterns": [
          {
            "contains":"grant_type=client_credentials",
            "notContain":"code="//how to make this??
          }
        ]
      },
      "response": {
        "bodyFileName": "token-400-response.json",
        "status": 400
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I don't know if this is important but these parameters are passed using: `x-www-form-urlencoded`

Scenario:
If the "grant_type" parameter is equal to authorization_code and the "code" parameter is not present, an error mock must be returned in the following format:

What I tried was to make the bodyPatterns this way:

```
"bodyPatterns": [
          {
            "matches": {
              "grant_type": "authorization_code",
              "code": "^$"
            }
          }
        ]
```

But I got the following error:

`matches operand must be a non-null string`

Answer (score 0):

The array that `bodyPatterns` requires has an implicit AND conjunction, meaning that each *object* in the array is a condition that must be met. So, in this case, we'll use one object that is `contains` and one that is `doesNotContain`.

```js
"bodyPatterns": [
      {
        "contains": "grant_type=authorization_code"
      },
      {
        "doesNotContain": "code="
      }
    ]
```

If, instead, the values are passed via a query parameter, we'll need to use the `queryParameters` field, which is also implicitly an AND conjunction. In order to specify that the `code` query parameter is missing, we can use `"absent": true`.

```js
"queryParameters": {
      "grant_type": {
        "equalTo": "authorization_code"
      },
      "code": {
        "absent": true
      }
    }
```

The same is true for form parameters, using the `formParameters` field (only available in WireMock 3.0.0+):

```js
"formParameters": {
      "grant_type": {
        "equalTo": "authorization_code"
      },
      "code": {
        "absent": true
      }
    }
```